# Stuck in a while loop after trying to refactor

Tags: c++

I tried to clean up a loop to make it a bit cleaner, but afterwards, it would get stuck inside the `while` loop. I tried to change the methods for checking the `set` but that hasn't worked out.

Original working code:

```cpp
unsigned seed = system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
minstd_rand0 generator(seed);
int BagNum = (generator() % 1000);
color = bagcolors[generator() % 5];
string BagCode = to_string(BagNum) + "-" + color;
if(!BagIDs.count(BagCode)) { //Working Code
    BagIDs.insert(BagCode);
    return BagCode;
} else { //Duplicate found, regens code
    string badcode;
    do {
        badcode = BagCode;
        BagCode.clear();
        BagNum = (generator() % 1000);
        color = bagcolors[generator() % 5];
        BagCode = to_string(BagNum) + "-" + color;
    } while(badcode == BagCode);
    BagIDs.insert(BagCode);
    return BagCode;
}
```

Cleanup Attempt:

```cpp
string BagCode,color;
while(!BagIDs.count(BagCode)) {
    unsigned seed = system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
    minstd_rand0 generator(seed);
    int BagNum = (generator() % 1000);
    color = bagcolors[generator() % 5];
    string BagCode = to_string(BagNum) + "-" + color;
}
```

Full method:

```cpp
string genBagCode() {
    static unordered_set<string> BagIDs;
    string bagcolors[5] = { "ORG", "BLK", "GRN", "BLU", "YLW" };
    string BagCode,color;
    while(!BagIDs.count(BagCode)) {
        unsigned seed = system_clock::now().time_since_epoch().count();
        minstd_rand0 generator(seed);
        int BagNum = (generator() % 1000);
        color = bagcolors[generator() % 5];
        string BagCode = to_string(BagNum) + "-" + color;
    }
    BagIDs.insert(BagCode);
    /*
    if (!BagIDs.count(BagCode)) { //Working Code
        BagIDs.insert(BagCode);
        return BagCode;
    } else { //Duplicate found, regens code
        string badcode;
        do {
            badcode = BagCode;
            BagCode.clear();
            BagNum = (generator() % 1000);
            color = bagcolors[generator() % 5];
            BagCode = to_string(BagNum) + "-" + color;
        } while(badcode == BagCode);
        BagIDs.insert(BagCode);
        return BagCode;
    }
    */
    return BagCode;
}
```

Comment: First, you should not generate a random number generator every time. One is sufficient. Move it out of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not adding to the BagIDs list inside the while loop.  Therefore the count is always 0.  I think the BagIDs.insert(BagCode) code should be above the previous brace.